# How do I insert a hyperlink into a Javascript randomizing text array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, hyperlink, random

Here's the code:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript"><!--

function text() {
};

text = new text();
number = 0;

// textArray        
text[number++] = "I read the other day some verses written by an eminent painter which were original and not conventional."         
text[number++] = "The soul always hears an admonition in such lines, let the subject be what it may."        
text[number++] = "The sentiment they instil is of more value than any thought they may contain."        
text[number++] = "To believe your own thought, to believe that what is in your private heart is true for all men, that is genius." 

increment = Math.floor(Math.random() * number);

document.write(text[increment]);

//--></SCRIPT>
```

Specifically what I'd like the words:

> true for you

from the fourth text in the array to link to some external website.

The `<a>` tag doesn't seem to work for me. Neither does the string method. Of course, I am a total lunkhead.

Comment: You have a syntax error (a quote that wasn't escaped). If that's the _HTML_, it also isn't close-quoted or close-tagged. You could have written an _Array literal_ instead of creating a custom constructor here. Lastly, [`document.write`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice) is a bad idea.

Comment: It's the portion of the HTML I'm working with, which I've borrowed from Javascript Source. I assume the code is close-quoted/close-tagged, though I'm too novice to know for sure. I also don't know what "array literal" nor "document.write" are, or what they do. (Lunkhead, you see). Are these all things that make my original question impossible to answer?

Comment: You have to start somewhere..

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is with the Quotes you insert when you use `a` tag, You should use the quotes in proper sense like below:

```
text[number++] = "I read the other day some verses written by an eminent painter which were original and not conventional"         
text[number++] = "The soul always hears an admonition in such lines, let the subject be what it may."        
text[number++] = "The sentiment they instil is of more value than any thought they may contain."
text[number++] = "To believe your own thought, to believe that what is in your private heart is <a href='javascript:void(0);'>true for </a> all men, that is genius."
```

**http://jsbin.com/luyod/2/**

Comment: I'm not interested in having the entire quote link to some other site, just a few words. Specifically, I'd like the words "true for you" from the fourth quote to link to an external site.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through this step by step,

1. Create a new `var`iable called `text`, and let it be an *Array*.

   ```
   var text = [];
   ```

   The `[]` here is an *Array literal*.
2. Populate the *Array* `text` with your *Strings*

   ```
   text.push("I read the other day some verses written by an eminent painter which were original and not conventional.");
   text.push("The soul always hears an admonition in such lines, let the subject be what it may.");
   text.push("The sentiment they instil is of more value than any thought they may contain.");
   text.push("To believe your own thought, to believe that what is in your private heart is true for all men, that is genius.";
   ```

   Here, `someArray.push` is a method which adds a new *item* to the *Array* `someArray`. Each new item gets it's own index and indices start from `0`.
3. Choose a random index from the *Array* `text` and assign it to a new `var`iable, `i`

   ```
   var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length);
   ```

   In *JavaScript*, the method `Math.random` returns a value *strictly less than `1`* but *greater than or equal to `0`*. This means we can multiply the value up by the number of items (or *length*) of an *Array*, then round down (or *floor*) this number to choose a random index from the *Array*.
4. In the *String* at *index* `i` of `text`, replace any occurance of `"true for you"` with your link. Let's give this the `var`iable name `str` so we can refer back to it.

   ```
   var str = text[i].replace(/true for you/g, "<a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com\">true for you</a>");
   ```

   Here, `/true for you/g` is a [***regular expression***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) or *RegExp*. The `g` at the end stands for `g`lobal and means "keep doing this until you reach the end".
5. Write this new *String* (that we called `str`) to your *#document* in your prefered way. As we can't see anything relating to your *HTML* markup, I'll keep your `document.write`, but this is considered [**bad practice**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice) so alternatives may be something you'd want to learn about in future.

   ```
   document.write(str);
   ```